# Different UITableViewCell styles

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, styles

'Default UITableViewCell styles from Apple should not be used'

Can somebody tell me what the previous sentence means. Is it possible to create your own style. If yes, how ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Statement simply isn't true.
If one of the Standard UITableViewCellStyles matches the layout and properties you want, then you should use them.
But if not build your own. ;)

Detailed documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7

If you want your own cell layout, subclass `UITableViewCell`!

Comment: I forgot to say this statement is just an instruction for some work I have to do. Anyway, thank you for your answer and your help.